# Finitely generated as an Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R,S$ be rings. Is the following equivalent to saying $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra?

"For some $n \in \mathbb{N} $ there exists a surjective ring homomorphism from $R[t_1,\dots,t_n]$ to $S$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. (I assume $R,S$ being commutative.) The two definitions are the following :

1. There is a $d\in\mathbf{N}$ and there are $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d \in S$ such that $S = R[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d]$ ;
2. There is an $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and a surjective morphism of rings $R[t_1,\ldots,t_n]\to S$ ;

and they are *equivalent*. Take $\alpha_i =$ image of $t_i$ in $S$ by your surjective morphism, you have $S = R[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n]$, so that 2 implies 1. Inversely, suppose $S$ to be finitely generated as an $R$ algebra : you have $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d \in S$ such that $S = R[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d]$, now define a morphism $R[t_1,\dots,t_n] \to S$ by sending $t_i$ to $\alpha_i$ for $1\leq i \leq d$, you get a surjective morphism by construction, so that 1 implies 2.

*Remark 1.* In fact one says *of finite type* instead of *finitely generated*, the latter being rather used for modules over a ring.

*Remark 2.* A third equivalent statement could be

3. There is an $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and an exact sequence $R[t_1,\dots,t_n] \to S \to 0$

Comment: Thanks. We hadn't really been given a definition in my course, but i thought this was what he seemed to mean.

Comment: Ok. By the way, the only two (equivalent by what I shown above) definitions I know (in the commutative case) are those I shown to be equivalent above. Advise : NEVER hesitate to ask to anyone (teacher or not) not defining something but using it what the definition is. ;-)

Comment: There could be : there is an exact sequence $R[t_1,\dots,t_n] \to S \to 0$, but as soon as you will know what an exact sequence is, you'll laugh and say : this is the same as what I already know. ;-)

Comment: I will edit my answer to include this, + a comment

Comment: I've seen exact sequences :)

Comment: Perfect, then !

Comment: I have a quick follow up question if that's ok? I can add it to the main question body if you want

Comment: actually I'm fine. Thanks!